# Checking to see whether the users input is correct with the correct version

Tags: python, list, file

OK, so what my program is all about is that the user has to solve a coded puzzle which gets read in from an external file. The user then guesses what letter matches up with the symbol in the coded  puzzle and they can then add this to a list of clues.

One of the options in my program allows the user to check whether the clues they have entered are correct with the solved version. The solved version is read in from an external file and this is what needs to get checked with the list of clues.

So far I have a basic piece of code but what keeps on happening is that the output I get is that " You scored 0 out of 10" even though some of the pairings I have entered are correct.

My code so far for this section of code is this...

```
def check_clues():
    count = 0
# TRIES TO OPEN FILE SOLVED.TXT
    try:
        with open('solved.txt') as r:
# READS THROUGH ALL THE LINES IN SOLVED.TXT
             solved = r.readlines()
# WILL DISPLAY AN ERROR MESSAGE IF SOLVED.TXT IS NOT FOUND
    except:
        print("Error finding file")
# WILL TRY AND OPEN THE FILE 'clues.txt'
    try:
        with open('clues.txt') as r: 
             clues = r.readlines()
    except:
        print("Error finding ")


# GOES THROUGH BOTH THE USERS CLUES AND SOLVED.TXT TO SEE HOW MANY CLUES ARE THE SAME
    for clue in clues:
        if clue in solved:
            count += 1
# Prints the amount of clues the user got right out of 10
    print('You got:', count, 'correct!')
```

Below is what is in the solved.txt file:

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

Below is what is in clues.txt

```
A#
M*
N%
```

However please note clues.txt is the list which the user can add to. So if the user decides to enter S and &, this will add to the clues.txt as S&

Below is the file words.txt which contains the list of coded words the user has to solve...

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

Comment: Can you fix your formatting please? Around `def check_clues():`

Comment: Do you mean indentation ?

Comment: What output do you expect? None of the lines in clues.txt is in solved.txt. So you get 0.

Comment: @Paul yes, the indentation

Comment: The output I expect is that it will display how many pairings the user got right... So something like this "You got 3 pairings correct"

Comment: In what way "correct"? "A#" and "M*" and "N%" are not lines in `solved.txt`. How are you expecting them to be matched?

Comment: OK let me add the coded words and it may make some more sense

Comment: I have indenteted the code khelwood

Comment: OK now I have added the coded words at the end of my question. So for example, if the user enters the D^ as a pairing, from looking at the solved file this is wrong because D is paired with ".

Answer (score 0):

I had a hand at this, using what you're provided. I believe this is what you're looking for provided you have all the files you listed. Basically I used the `words.txt` and `solved.txt` files and created a dictionary mapping all the symbols to their correct letters. Then I used that dictionary to compare each clue to see if they match. This would increment the count and you would get your correct output.

The problem with your original code is that you're simply searching if the clue is inside of the solved text file. For example, you search if your first clue `A*` is inside of the words text file. Obviously it isn't because there isn't a `*` in that file. So you need something to baseline/compare it to. Which is why in this case I created a dictionary. I also removed your try/except loops since your program should technically never run if a file is missing. In which case your exceptions will allow the program to keep running even if a file is missing producing multiple error outputs. It should stop if no files are found or be handled specifically, not allow it to keep running as it normally would. If you go that route, I'd also advise only using `except WindowsError` to avoid catching any other potential exceptions.

```
def check_clues():
    # Dictionary to hold all of the symbol/letter combos
    coded_dict = {}

    # Go through each symbol/letter combination together
    with open("words.txt") as fw, open("solved.txt") as fs:
        for fw_line, fs_line in zip(fw, fs):
            for fw_symbol, fs_letter in zip(fw_line.strip(), fs_line.strip()):
                # Add the symbol/letter combination to the dictionary
                coded_dict[fw_symbol] = fs_letter

    correct_clues = []
    with open("clues.txt") as fc:
        for fc_line in fc:
            # If the symbol is in the dictionary and the letter matches the symbol
            if fc_line[1] in coded_dict and coded_dict[fc_line[1]] == fc_line[0]:
                # Add a correct clue to your list
                correct_clues.append(fc_line.strip())

    print("You got a total of {0} correct: {1}".format(len(correct_clues), ", ".join(correct_clues)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_clues()
```

If you need me to elaborate on anything let me know.

Comment: At this point of the code print "You got a total of %i correct" % count there is a syntax error...

Comment: Works fine for me, can you post a full traceback? Also what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also I really do appreciate what you have done however would you be able to do this in a list?

Comment: Where would you want a list? The only place I would recommend a list would be to maybe have a list of which clues were correct. The symbol/letter combo is almost an ideal setup for a dictionary.

Comment: 3.4.1 ... line 174, in check_clues
    print ("You got a total of %i correct") % count
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: OK, Could you amend this in your answer?

Comment: See the edited answer, added a list to keep track of all of your correct clues.

Comment: Without knowing what else is in your menu I can't possibly know if/how it interferes with it. Realistically it shouldn't interfere at all, however if you're using it in another program make sure you only copy over the method, not the `__name__ == "main"` part. Edit: Yeah, remove the main if, that's only for standalone purposes.

Comment: This is my full code on this website for you to understand more... http://repl.it/Zme

Comment: After removing those two lines from the code you provided it interprets past that however encounters other errors in your code that you haven't posted (line 222). To examine those syntax errors open another question.

Comment: Great, it is working much better now ! However when I enter another pairing which is correct, it is now saying that I still got 3 clues correct... So what I think is happening is that the clues which I am entering, doesn't seem to be adding to the list to be solved with...